# Difference between a string read from a text file and a string in a variable in Python

Tags: python, nlp

I am writing some python code which will read in textual data from text files and look for the three words to the left and right of a word or a phrase contained in a python list.  I wrote the initial code using a sentence stored as a python string and then converted it to reading from a text file.  This is the original code.

```
work_list = ["for all good", "to the aid", "for all practical purposes", "all", "to", "aid", "Now"]

txt = "Now is the time to aid and for all practical purposes for all good men to come to the aid of the party"

for element in work_list:
 if element in txt: # was string in earlier version
  s = txt.split()
  # print(f'"{element}" found in file {txt}')
  # was string
  element_split = element.split()
  before = element_split[0] #get first word
  after = element_split[-1] #get last word

  three_before = "" # circumvents warning message 'variable can be initially undefined'
  for i, w in enumerate(s):  # it gives a list items a number
   if w in before: # if the first word in the phrase/word is in the string
    three_before = s[(i - 3):i] if i > 1 else ''
    three_before = ' '.join(word for word in three_before)

         # get the three words after the last word in the phrase/string
   if w in after:  # if the last word in the phrase/string is in the string
      three_after = s[(i+1):(i + 4)] if i  < len(s) else ''
      three_after = ' '.join(word for word in three_after)
      print("%s <%s> %s" % (three_before, element, three_after))
```

Which produces the following output.

```
is the time <to the aid> and for all
men to come <to the aid> of the party
to aid and <for all practical purposes> for all good
aid and for <all> practical purposes for
practical purposes for <all> good men to
is the time <to> aid and for
all good men <to> come to the
men to come <to> the aid of
the time to <aid> and for all
come to the <aid> of the party
 <Now> is the time
```

The code to read from a text file looks like this

```
work_list = ["for all good", "to the aid", "for all practical purposes", "all", "to", "aid", "Now"]


path = 'D:/Testing10'


context_d = {}
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        f = open(filename)
        txt = f.read()
        txt = txt.lower()
        s = txt
        s = [item.replace('May', '') for item in s]  # locate and replace all months of May before lowering
        s = [item.replace('\n', '') for item in s]
        s = [item.replace('\\n', '') for item in s]
       # s = [item.replace('\\', '') for item in txt]
       # s = [item.replace('\\s', '') for item in txt]

        for element in work_list:
         if element in txt: # was string in earlier version
          # print(f'"{element}" found in file {string}')
           # was string
          s= txt.split()

          element_split = element.split()
          before = element_split[0] #get first word
          after = element_split[-1] #get last word

          three_before = "" # circumvents warning message 'variable can be initially undefined'
          for i, w in enumerate(s):  # it gives to the list items numbers
           if w in before: # if the first word in the phrase/word is in the string
            three_before = s[(i - 3):i] if i > 1 else ''
            three_before = ' '.join(word for word in three_before)

           #    get the three words after the last word in the phrase/string
           if w in after:  # if the last word in the phrase/string is in the string
            three_after = s[(i+1):(i + 4)] if i  < len(s) else ''
            three_after = ' '.join(word for word in three_after)
            print("%s <%s> %s" % (three_before, element, three_after))
```

Which produces the following output

```
all practical purposes <for all good> men to come
to aid for <all> practical purposes for
practical purposes for <all> good men to
is the time <to> aid for all
all good men <to> come to the
men to come <to> the aid of
the time to <aid> for all practical
come to the <aid> of the party
```

The code reading the text fie containing the sentence is not detecting the phrases "for all practical purposes" and "to the aid".  Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and if there is a better way to find the words three spaces left and right of the word/phrase (it is very important that this algorithm can pick up all phrases)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `[item.replace('May', '') for item in s]` will not work. `item` is single characters, not words. And you're turning the string into a list of characters.

Comment: Later you do `s= txt.split()`. This is going back to the original `txt` without any of the earlier replacements.

Comment: I suspect your file contains `\r` characters.

Comment: I've converted all the replace s with txt and then assigned txt to s, which means I'm no longer using a string from a read/IO but using a string list.  It produces no output at all.

Comment: It should be `txt = txt.replace(...)`, with no list comprehensions. Is that what you have?

Comment: I've replaced all items with txt, there is no output at all.

Comment: Add the contents of the text file to the question.

Comment: It's the same as the first code listing, one line of text.  But in practice it will have to deal with much larger text files between 10-150kb

Comment: What are all the replacements for?

Comment: They're  for use with the real data.  This .txt file is just "toy data" to test whether or not the algorithm will work with something smaller to begin with.

Comment: If it doesn't work, the problem most likely has something to do with the replacements. For instance, you probably want to replace newline with space, not an empty string, so you don't get words running together.

Comment: I've commented out all the replace statements and on running it again it produces the same output as when I started.

Comment: The version with a literal doesn't have any newlines in the text. The file has newlines. So they're not the same.

Comment: The only difference is that one reads `txt` from the file, the other gets it from a literal. So the problem MUST be that the contents of `txt` are different.

Comment: As I said in an earlier post, it works fine with a literal variable or a identical string in a text file (toy data) but is not working correctly when I run it on a real text file, producing spurious output.  Back to the drawing board.

Comment: I know you said that, but think of it logically. The rest of the code doesn't know or care where the data came from. So if the data were actually the same, it would have to produce the same results. So the problem must be the data.